# Display recent post at 4th postition

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display recent post at 4th position of loop.

for e.g i have 1 to 10 post and 10 number of post is a recent post and i would like to display it at 4th position.

here is my code.

```
<?php
$blog_arg = array('post_type'=>'post','posts_per_page'=>7,'order'=>'DESC', 'orderby'=> 'most_recent',);
$get_blogs = new WP_QUERY($blog_arg);

if($get_blogs->have_posts()){
    global $post;
    $count =1;
    while($get_blogs->have_posts()) : $get_blogs->the_post();
        $category_name = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category', array("fields" => "names"));

        if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
            <div class="blog_posts" style="background:#767b7b url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>) ; ">
        <?php
        }else{
           if($count %2 == 0){
                echo ' <div class="blog_posts" style="background:#909696">';
            }else{
               echo ' <div class="blog_posts" style="background:#767b7b">';
            }
        }

        if($count == 4){
            echo "Display Recent post heree..";
        }
     ?>

            <div class="verti-middal-main">
                 <h3><?php echo $post->post_title;?></h3>
                 <span><?php echo $category_name[0]; ?></span>
                 <div class="blog-sort-disk"><?php echo wp_trim_words( $post->post_content, 20, '' );?></div>
                 <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">READ MORE</a>
            </div>
             <div id="blog_loading_loader" ></div>
        </div>
    <?php
    $count++;
    endwhile;
}?>
```

i tried but recent post not appearing at 4th position so how could i display recent post (10 number of post) at 4th position.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the tenth element graphically in position four?

If so, my suggestion is to put all the elements of each post in a custom array and with something like:

```
while($get_blogs->have_posts()) : $get_blogs->the_post();
   $custom_array_of_posts[]['title'] = $post->post_title;
endwhile;
//Then you could use this array and print whenever you need
// Using a foreach for example

$custom_array_of_posts[10][title] //Access the title of tenth post
```

You could control the display of elements carefully.

Hope this help.

Comment: if my post count is increase then , every time i change the value of array.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question. 
You have 10 posts, and you want to print the tenth in 4th position?